# Android 6.0 get automatically permission without prompt

Tags: android, android-permissions

I always Getting a Permission Prompt by default while installing a new app. How can i give permission without prompt while developing app.

Comment: put targetSdk below 23 in your gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your target SDK version to less then 23, i.e. 22 or below in your module's build.gradle file if you do not want to prompt for permission while running the app.